# Make jquery isotope sort descending by default

Tags: sorting, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I am making a site with a lot of pictures and videos using Bootstrap and Isotope. Each video/picture has an ID (called "nyeste") and a score, and I want both nyeste and score to sort descending, when users press the link "score" or "nyeste"

I have copy pasted a lot from isotope and the relevant code looks like this:

```
<ul id="sort-by" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="sortBy">
  <li><a href="#sortBy=score"  data-option-value="score">score</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sortBy=nyeste"  data-option-value="nyeste">nyeste</a></li>
</ul>

....

<ul id="sort-direction" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="sortAscending">
  <li><a href="#sortAscending=true" data-option-value="true" class="selected">sort ascending</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sortAscending=false" data-option-value="false">sort descending</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I combine these two functions, so that both "score" and "nyeste" sort ascending without users having to press two different links?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the descending works as default for all your sorting rules.

Just add [`sortAscending: false`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#sortascending):

```
$container.isotope({    
    itemSelector: '.element', 
    sortAscending: false, // <---------------- HERE
    getSortData: {  
        symbol: function ($elem) {  
            return $elem.attr('data-symbol');  
        },  
        category: function ($elem) {  
            return $elem.attr('data-category');  
        },  
        number: function ($elem) {  
            return parseInt($elem.find('.number').text(), 10);  
        },  
        weight: function ($elem) {  
            return parseFloat($elem.find('.weight').text().replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));  
        },  
        name: function ($elem) {  
            return $elem.find('.name').text();  
        }  
    }
});
```